# how to see full query with values in ponyorm

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, ponyorm

Today i am using the sql_debug(True) that helps me to see the queries but without the values.

How could i see how ponyorm translate the query with values ?

Thank you very much.
This is an example of query i'm using.

```
    with db_session:
    access = select(p for p in Access if raw_sql('( lower(first_name) = lower($first_name) and  lower(last_name) = lower($last_name) ) '
                                                            'or ( lower(first_name) = lower($last_name) and lower(last_name) = lower($first_name) ) '
                                                            'or (lower(facebook_url) = lower($facebook_url)) '
                                                            'or (lower(twitter_url) = lower($twitter_url)) '
                                                            'or (lower(linkedin_url) = lower($linkedin_url)) '))
        .order_by(desc(Access.twitter_url),desc(Access.facebook_url),desc(Access.linkedin_url),
                  desc(Access.facebook_url))
print(access.get_sql())
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a method called `get_sql()`

```
query_obj = select(c for c in Category if c.name.startswith('v'))
sql = query_obj.get_sql()
print(sql)
```

output:

```
SELECT "c"."id", "c"."name"
FROM "category" "c"
WHERE "c"."name" LIKE 'v%%'
```

code continue:

```
for obj in query_obj:
    print('id:', obj.id, 'name:', obj.name)
```

output:

```
id: 1 name: viki
```

here is a link to the docs https://docs.ponyorm.com/api_reference.html#Query.get_sql

You can log the sql or simply print it.

Update:

> > OP updated the question:

If the sql query has a variable like `$name` it is passed as a sql parameter.

```
first_name = 'viki'
query = select(c for c in Category if raw_sql('( lower(name) = lower($first_name))'))
query.get_sql()
```

so `get_sql()` will return the value with a placeholder, and the output will look like this:

```
 'SELECT "c"."id", "c"."name", "c"."age"\nFROM "Category" "c"\nWHERE ( lower(name) = lower(?))'
```

If we want no placeholders should be there in the query then we can avoid passing direct sql to query and instead build it separately in python.

Like this:

```
query = select(c for C in Category if c.name == 'viki')
query.get_sql()
```

output:

```
'SELECT "c"."id", "c"."name", "c"."age"\nFROM "Category" "c"\nWHERE "c"."name" = \'viki\''
```

Comment: great thanks, but it still doesn't show the values, i want the end sql result with the values. 

SELECT "c"."id", "c"."name"
FROM "category" "c"
WHERE "c"."name" LIKE 'some value'

Comment: @Yan Doesn't it do exactly that `WHERE "c"."name" LIKE 'v%%'` in sql?

Comment: It does. 
But i want to see the value instead 'v%%'

Comment: @Yan my friend 'v%%' is the value. if you put a query `if c.name == 'viki'` then you will get output like `"c"."name" = 'viki'`. I hope you are getting the point. If not please elaborate as much as you can with an example. And add it in the question.

Comment: nop, i don't shows 'viki'
i did it and i see: 
lower(%(p1)s) and  lower(last_name) = lower(%(p2)s) ) or ( lower(first_name) = lower(%(p3)s.........

Comment: @Yan that is happening because you are probably passing the wrong value or there is a bug in `ponyorm`. Please share your code and we can look into it.

Comment: I edited the question you can take a look on the query

Comment: The SQL query you are passing is wrong. Will formulate a correct one and share it later. On mobile right now.

Comment: I hope I have answered your question. If not I would advise you to revert the question back to the old question and create a new question with your query so someone else would be able to help you with it. Thanks

Comment: ok now i am understand, thanks for the answer, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
logging.getLogger(__name__).debug('SQL:\n\n\t\t\t%s\n', '\n'.join(unicode(x) for x in request._construct_sql_and_arguments()[:2]).replace('\n', '\n\t\t\t'))
```

for that.
For example,

```
19:30:01.902 data.py:231 [DEBUG]  SQL:

        SELECT "x"."_id", "x"."filename", "x"."_created", "x"."_updated"
        FROM "reports" "x"
        WHERE "x"."_id" <= ?
          AND "x"."_created" >= ?
        (50, '2019-04-17 19:30:01.900028')
```

will be printed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_sql_debug(debug=True, show_values=True)`.

Reference [here](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/blob/orm/pony/orm/core.py#L83).